# "open" toggle button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I stop the "button" ("send a message") close toggle function when the toggle menu is open so that the only way to close the toggle menu is by clicking "send"?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").hide();

    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        $("#container").toggle();
        this.value = this.value == 'send message' ? 'contact' : 'send message';
    });

    $("#button2").on('click', function() {
        $("#container").toggle();
        $("#button").val('thank you');
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="contact" />
<br />
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="send" />
</div>
```

Comment: `How can I stop the "button"("send a message") close toggle function when the toggle menu is open so that the only way to close the toggle menu is by clicking "send" ???` Please explain a bit clearly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
$("#container").toggle();
this.value = this.value == 'send message' ? 'contact' : 'send message';
});
```

to

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
if($("#container").is(":visible"))
    return false;

$("#container").toggle();
this.value = this.value == 'send message' ? 'contact' : 'send message';
});
```

This checks if the container is visible already, if it is then it stops the event handler from continuing.

You may need to set the container to display: none; in your css by default depending on if the container is technically visible when the button is clicked but obscured from view as jquery .is(":visible") isn't the most intuitive method in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the initial button and then show it again when the user clicks send:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#container").hide();

    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        $("#container").toggle();
        $(this).hide();
    });

     $("#button2").on('click', function() {
        $("#container").toggle();
        $("#button").val('thank you');
        $("#button").show();
    });
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7n07m0p/1/)